TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push') in Angular Material Dialog Testing
The previous answers to this question do not resolve my issue.
I'm encountering a TypeError while testing a method in my Angular component that opens a dialog to delete a user. The error message states:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
at MatDialog.open (node_modules/@angular/material/fesm2022/dialog.mjs:598:26)
at MatDialog.open (node_modules/@angular/material/fesm2022/dialog.mjs:598:26)
at UserComponent.deleteUser (src/app/components/user/user.component.ts:108:35)
at UserContext.apply (src/app/components/user/user.component.spec.ts:147:15)
at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:369:28)
at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:2081:39)
at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:368:34)
at ZoneImpl.run (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:111:43)
at runInTestZone (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:216:38)
at UserContext. (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:234:32)
at 
at UserContext.apply (src/app/components/user/user.component.spec.ts:147:15)
at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:369:28)
at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:2081:39)
at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:368:34)
at ZoneImpl.run (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:111:43)
at runInTestZone (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:216:38)

Here's the relevant portion of my UserComponent:
deleteUser(userId: number, userNickname: string): void {
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DeleteDialogComponent, {
    height: '400px',
    width: '550px',
    data: { userId, userNickname },
  });

  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    if (result) {
      const subscription = this.userService.deleteUser(userId).subscribe({
        next: () => {
          console.log("Ok!")
        },
        error: error => {
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

And here is my test setup:
describe('UserComponent', () => {
  let component: UserComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UserComponent>;
  let userServiceMock: jasmine.SpyObj<UserService>;
  let routerMock: jasmine.SpyObj<Router>;
  let dialogSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<MatDialog>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    userServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj<UserService>('UserService', {
      deleteUser: of(1)
    });
    routerMock = jasmine.createSpyObj<Router>('Router', ['navigate']);
    dialogSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('MatDialog', ['open']);

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [UserComponent, MatDialogModule, BrowserAnimationsModule],
      providers: [
        { provide: UserService, useValue: userServiceMock },
        { provide: Router, useValue: routerMock },
        { provide: MatDialog, useValue: dialogSpy }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should open modal and delete user', () => {
    const userId = 1;
    const userNickname = 'JohnSmith';

    component.deleteUser(userId, userNickname);

    const dialogRef = dialogSpy.open.calls.mostRecent().returnValue;
    dialogRef.afterClosed = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(of(true));

    component.deleteUser(userId, userNickname);
    
    expect(userServiceMock.deleteUser).toHaveBeenCalledWith(userId);
  });
});

The line this.openDialogs.push(dialogRef); in the MatDialog implementation seems to be the source of the issue.
I suspect that the dialogRef is not being created correctly during the test, but I'm unsure how to resolve this.
How can I ensure that dialogRef is correctly mocked so that the openDialogs array is not undefined?
Are there any adjustments I need to make to my test setup or the deleteUser method to avoid this error?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

You should spyOn open method and return an object that contains the property afterClosed, this will be a function which returns on observable.
We can use fakeAsync and flush to wait for the async observable to complete, then verify the result.
it('should open modal and delete user', fakeAsync(() => {
  const userId = 1;
  const userNickname = 'JohnSmith';
  dialogSpy.open.and.returnValue({
    afterClosed: () => of(true),
  } as any);
  component.deleteUser(userId, userNickname);
  flush();
  expect(userServiceMock.deleteUser).toHaveBeenCalledWith(userId);
}));

Full Code:
import {
  TestBed,
  ComponentFixture,
  waitForAsync,
  fakeAsync,
  flush,
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent, UserService } from './app.component';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let userServiceMock: jasmine.SpyObj<UserService>;
  let routerMock: jasmine.SpyObj<Router>;
  let dialogSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<MatDialog>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    userServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj<UserService>('UserService', {
      deleteUser: of(1),
    });
    routerMock = jasmine.createSpyObj<Router>('Router', ['navigate']);
    dialogSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('MatDialog', ['open']);

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
      providers: [
        { provide: UserService, useValue: userServiceMock },
        { provide: Router, useValue: routerMock },
        { provide: MatDialog, useValue: dialogSpy },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should open modal and delete user', fakeAsync(() => {
    const userId = 1;
    const userNickname = 'JohnSmith';
    dialogSpy.open.and.returnValue({
      afterClosed: () => of(true),
    } as any);
    component.deleteUser(userId, userNickname);
    flush();
    expect(userServiceMock.deleteUser).toHaveBeenCalledWith(userId);
  }));
});

Stackblitz Demo
